# Const initial vectors in MDS

Tags: python, optimization

I need to use MDS, but some initial vectors in MDS must be const when others are calculating.

Example:

```
vector1 - const
vector2 - const
vector3 - const
...
vector10 - mutable
vector11 - mutable
vector12 - mutable
...
```

So, only vectors 10,11,12... are changeable by a distance matrix.

Do we have a tool for that in python?

Comment: MDS is based on distances, but you don't have any distances, you have points. If you perform MDS on a distance matrix computed from a set of points you will always get the identity function, because the original distance matrix was already consistent. So you're missing something here.

Comment: @orlp, Yeah, but in some implementation, we can set base values of vectors. I mean I know distances between const points, and I only need to find other points(could be random).  So, I assume we can change mutable points to minimize distances, and don't touch const points, and that's all.
Maybe I don't understand something, maybe I need another method.

Comment: @orlp, if you know a method where we are able to set base points - it'll be great.